# Using Java8 Streams to create a list of objects from another two lists

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following Java6 and Java8 code:

```
List<ObjectType1> lst1 = // a list of ObjectType1 objects
List<ObjectType2> lst2 = // a list of ObjectType1 objects, same size of lst1

List<ObjectType3> lst3 = new ArrayLis<ObjectType3>(lst1.size());
for(int i=0; i < lst1.size(); i++){
  lst3.add(new ObjectType3(lst1.get(i).getAVal(), lst2.get(i).getAnotherVal()));
}
```

Is there any way in Java8 to handle the previous for in a more concise way using Lambda?

Comment: Can you provide the actual constructor of `ObjectType3`?

Comment: Why use streams here? Your existing loop works fine and a stream will be _less_ readable

Comment: @fge I know. I want a single line solution. About readability, in my opinion it is only a question of practice. I can understand on the fly the given solution. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: OK, but "single line" and "faster" are not the same... And it's very easy to do unreadable single liners (I know, I also do perl) :p

Comment: @fge I know, my question was looking for a more concise way, not faster!

Comment: @fge Moreover, wrt the accepted answer, I have to say that you can also use `IntStream.range(0, lst1.size()).parallel()` and thus eventually speedup your execution time!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A Stream is tied to a given iterable/Collection so you can't really "iterate" two collections in parallel.

One workaround would be to create a stream of indexes but then it does not necessarily improve over the for loop. The stream version could look like:

```
List<ObjectType3> lst3 = IntStream.range(0, lst1.size())
         .mapToObj(i -> new ObjectType3(lst1.get(i).getAVal(), lst2.get(i).getAnotherVal()))
         .collect(toList());
```

Comment: @mat_boy it's not really shorter than what you had before.  It sure is clever but I wouldnt consider it an improvement.  Java8 doesnt deprecate a classic for loop :)

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx Sure, but I can assign the return value in a single line. I know, it is not important, but I prefer this approach.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx Clearly if you write `IntStream.range(0, lst1.size()).parallel()` thus you may eventually speedup your execution time! This is a good point, isn't it? :)

Comment: euhm, sure.  But it smells like premature optimization to me.  Readability of your code should always be your first concern.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a method that transforms two collections into a new collection, like this:

```
public <T, U, R> Collection<R> singleCollectionOf(final Collection<T> collectionA, final Collection<U> collectionB, final Supplier<Collection<R>> supplier, final BiFunction<T, U, R> mapper) {
    if (Objects.requireNonNull(collectionA).size() != Objects.requireNonNull(collectionB).size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    Objects.requireNonNull(supplier);
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
    Iterator<T> iteratorA = collectionA.iterator();
    Iterator<U> iteratorB = collectionB.iterator();
    Collection<R> returnCollection = supplier.get();
    while (iteratorA.hasNext() && iteratorB.hasNext()) {
        returnCollection.add(mapper.apply(iteratorA.next(), iteratorB.next()));
    }
    return returnCollection;
}
```

The important part here is that it will map the obtained `iteratorA.next()` and `iteratorB.next()` into a new object.

It is called like this:

```
List<Integer> list1 = IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> list2 = IntStream.range(0, 10).map(n -> n * n + 1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
singleCollectionOf(list1, list2, ArrayList::new, Pair::new).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

In your example it would be:

```
List<ObjectType3> lst3 = singleCollectionOf(lst1, lst2, ArrayList::new, ObjectType3::new);
```

Where for example `Pair::new` is a shorthand for the lamdda `(t, u) -> new Pair(t, u)`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to update 1 stream to another, however, I accomplished a similar feat using a Map. :)

```
    Map<Integer, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    for(int index = 100; index > 0; index--){
        result.put(index, String.valueOf(index));
    }
    result.keySet().stream()
            .filter(key -> key%3 == 0)
            .sorted()
            .forEach(key -> result.put(key, "Fizz"));

    result.keySet().stream()
            .filter(key -> key%5 == 0)
            .sorted()
            .forEach(key -> result.put(key, "Buzz"));

    result.keySet().stream()
            .filter(key -> key%3 == 0 && key%5 == 0)
            .sorted()
            .forEach(key -> result.put(key, "FizzBuzz"));

    result.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> System.out.println(result.get(key)));
```

Comment: This answer is completely our of scope!

Comment: Seems to match the problem description: "Using Java8 Streams to create a list of objects from another" A map can be defined as 2 lists of Objects, with a 1 to 1 mapping from domain to range. Programming is all about creative solutions.

Comment: In my example I use List not Map. These are two different interfaces, As I said, I needed lists.