# Convert List<MyObject> to List<List<String>> using java8 lambdas only

Tags: java, list, collections, lambda, java-8

I have `List<User>` where `User` is a class having variable `id,name,date` .I just want to create a `List<List<String>>` with it such that it only contains name and date from the first list.My Code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class User
{
  int id;
  String name;
  Date date;

  public User(int id,String name,Date date){
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.date=date;

  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    User one=new User(1,"a",new Date());
    User two=new User(2,"b",new Date());
    User three=new User(3,"c",new Date());

    List<User> userList=Arrays.asList(one,two,three);

    System.out.println(userList);

    List<List<String>> stringList = IntStream.range(0,userList.size())
                                             .maptoObj(i -> Array.asList(userList.get(i).name,userList.get(i).date))
                                             .collect(toList);
    System.out.print(stringList);

  }
}
```

I cant seem to figure out how can I achieve that when I use `collect()`it says cannot find the symbol on collect. Is there any way I can get `List<List<String>>` containing List of name and date from `List<User>`

I also tried

```
List<List<String>> stringList = IntStream.range(0,userList.size())
                                         .map(i -> Arrays.asList(userList.get(i).name,userList.get(i).date.toString()))
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it gave me

```
 error: 
    no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to int
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>asList(T...)incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
                                             .map(i -> Arrays.asList(userList.get(i).name,userList.get(i).date.toString()))
                                                                    ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to put `Date` objects into a list of strings?

Comment: Your mistake is on `collect(toList)`, `toList` does not exist, it's `toList()`.

Comment: @marstran no I want to convert it to string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to use an `IntStream`.

```
List<List<String>> output = 
    userList.stream()
            .map (u -> Arrays.asList (u.name,u.date.toString()))
            .collect (Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT:

If you wish to stay with the `IntStream` solution :

```
List<List<String>> stringList = 
    IntStream.range(0,userList.size())
             .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.asList(userList.get(i).name,userList.get(i).date.toString()))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: can it be done with  `Intsream` I tried it with removing the `collect` error but it dint work(edited my question) actually I was trying something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/22933355/3841803

Comment: yes, I have updated my question with that .Having hard time understanding these new features in java 8

Comment: @singhakash If you stick to the IntStream solution, you should use `mapToObj` instead of `map`.

Comment: sorry if this is weird but can you give some tips on learning lambdas and new feature in java 8.I am having difficulty understanding it like in the above you changed map to mapToObject how do you know that?

Comment: @codegasmer Any new API takes time to learn. Just Google Java 8 Lambda expressions and Java 8 Streams. That's how I learned.