# Create list of map using streams and lambda expressions

Tags: collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

```
for (String varValue : arrayList1) {
                Map<String, String> mapInstance = new HashMap<>();
                val.put(KEY, VALUE);
                val.put(VAR_KEY, varValue);
                arrayList2.add(mapInstance);
            }
```

Basically, I want to create a map with two entries and then add each of these maps to a list.

**Final list:**

```
{KEY,VALUE}   {VAR_KEY,arrayList1.get(0)}
{KEY,VALUE}   {VAR_KEY,arrayList1.get(1)}
{KEY,VALUE}   {VAR_KEY,arrayList1.get(2)}
...
and so on
```

Comment: Ok and what are you stuck on? Did you read the Stream tutorial? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/

Comment: Yes. I am able to create the list with map having a only one entry, but how do I create a map with multiple entries?

Comment: Can you post what you have then?

Comment: I have the same solution as..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933296/using-java8-streams-to-create-a-list-of-objects-from-another

Comment: Those linked answers do not mention maps. I'm not sure what you're linking me to. But the idea is the same yes: create a Stream from the input list, use `map` to create and return a new `HashMap` and collect into a list.

Comment: I mean just the way he is creating an internal list, I want to create an internal map, BUT with two different rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120267/discussion-between-qualtar-demix-and-tunaki).

Comment: Streams can do this nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648200/how-to-create-list-of-maps-from-list-of-object-in-java-without-having-getkey-met

Answer (score 4):

It seems you only need a simple `map` stage.

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = arrayList1.stream().map(t -> {
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("KEY", "VALUE");
  map.put("VAR_KEY", t);
  return map;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

What is KEY and VAR_KEY? are they instance variable of some object which you are trying to put in Map from the incoming object.

However, you can try something like this : 
Map result =
                arrayList1.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Class::getKey, c -> c));